# Freeze x-axis on a chart while using R shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-server, r-plotly

This is the code to plot a gantt chart in R Shiny. What should i add to it for the following two things:-

1. Freeze x-axis, so that i don't have to scroll down to bottom to see x-axis, this being a huge chart.
2. Format tooltip to include start time line, end timeline,timeline type & location name and not the 
   random stuff appearing in it presently.

   ```
   i_test <- ggplotly(i_test)%>%
     layout(legend = list(orientation ='v', x = 1.2, y = 1)) 

   div(style= 'max-height:1000px; overflow-y: scroll; position: relative',
       plotlyOutput(i_test))

   if (interactive()) {
     library(shiny)
     library(bs4Dash)
     shinyApp(
       ui = bs4DashPage(
         bs4DashNavbar(),
         bs4DashSidebar(),
         bs4DashControlbar(),
         bs4DashBody(
           fluidRow(
           bs4Box(plotlyOutput('radar', height = 10000), width = 10),
           bs4Box(img(src="bsc_logo.png", align = "right",height='10px'),width=2)


           )         

         ),
         title = "AttachmentBlock"
       ),
       server = function(input, output) { 
         output$radar <- renderPlotly({
       a <- list(tickangle = 45)
           ggplotly(i_test) 
         })

         }
     )
   }
   ```

As of now the ouput i am getting is 
[image]